# string.Split() and an if statement

Tags: c#, split

I have a text file which I split with a `\n`.

text file (test) reads

```
1
2
3
4
```

now the confusing part.

code

```
string test = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Custom tests\"+testselect.Text+".txt");

string[] check = test.Split('\n');

if (check[0] == "1")
{
     label.Text = "whatever";
}
```

this does not work. The label stays default value. however if I :

```
label.Text = check[0];
```

the label displays a 1.

I do not understand this please help.

Comment: There is a good chance your file is a windows text file, in which case, lines are "\r\n" not simply "\n" so each string in your array might be "1\r" etc.  See Reed's answer.

Comment: it might not even be splitted i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - you should be able to just use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) instead of reading the text and splitting....

You may need to trim the results.  If there is extra whitespace on the lines, the condition may fail.  Try using:

```
if (check[0].Trim() == "1")
{
```

This will trim off any whitespace, which should cause your conditional to succeed.

You can also put a breakpoint in, and inspect the values in the debugger.  This will help you better diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use Environment.NewLine.  Different operating systems use different newline characters.

[What is the universal newline for all operating systems? (LF and CR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720612/what-is-the-universal-newline-for-all-operating-systems-lf-and-cr)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just comparing numbers? Need to check case and whitespace..

```
string.Equals(check[0].Trim(), "some value", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

Remove the returns if there are any

```
string[] check = test.Replace("\r", "").Split('\n');

        if(check[0] == "1")
```

or split by new line and take the character in the array and check that.

```
string[] check = test.Split('\n');

        if(check[0][0] == '1')
```

I would use option two.

EDIT:

Or something like this, but its a bit OTT and you get all of the \r\n

```
 char[] check = test.SplitMeUp();

        if(check[0] == '1')


 static class Extensions
{
    public static char[] SplitMeUp(this string str)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[str.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
            chars[i] = str[i];

        return chars;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Something else to filter out specific characters

```
public static char[] SplitMeUp(this string str, char[] filterChars = null)
    {
        List<Char> chars = new List<char>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if(filterChars != null && filterChars.Length > 0 && filterChars.Contains(str[i]))
                    continue; 

            chars.Add(str[i]);
        }

        return chars.ToArray();
    }
```

and use it like

```
char[] check = test.SplitMeUp(new char[] {'\r', '\n'});

        if(check[0] == '1')
```

it will ignore all of those \r\n and just split everything up.