# db, mov, string literals

Tags: assembly, nasm

Is the below instruction in `message:` an correct? Specifically, because "Hello, World", is a total of `12` bytes, however, the right operand has "10".

I wanted to know if that is an error. If not, why does it specify 10 as the right operand? I got this code from here: (http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/x86assembly/)

Also, in `mov rdx,13` why does it specify 13 bytes and not the actual size of `message`?

```
    global _start

    section .text
_start:
    ; write(1, message, 13)
    mov     rax, 1            ; system call write is 1
    mov     rdi, 1            ; 1 is stdout
    mov     rsi, message      ; address of string
    mov     rdx, 13           ; number of bytes
    syscall           ; invoke operating system call

    ; exit(0)
    mov eax, 60       ; system call 60 is exit
    xor rdi, rdi      ; exit code 0
    syscall           ; invoke exit
message:
    db  "Hello, World", 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If not, why does it specify 10 as the right operand?

The 10 is a newline character after the string. 10 in ASCII is LF (line feed) which is newline on Unix/Linux systems. [On other systems it's different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720612/what-is-the-universal-newline-for-all-operating-systems-lf-and-cr).

> why does it specify 13 bytes and not the actual size of message?

13 bytes is the size of the message (12 bytes) plus the newline character (1 byte)